# instr() in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
SQL> select instr('stringrings','rin',-4,1) from dual;

INSTR('STRINGRINGS','RIN',-4,1)
-------------------------------
                              7
```

when i provide the search position as -4 and it searches backward from right to left, it returns the match position as 7 though  the whole pattern does not match from the given search starting position. here only the partial pattern matches in the original string.

```
SQL> select instr('stringrings','rin',-5,1) from dual;

INSTR('STRINGRINGS','RIN',-5,1)
-------------------------------
                              7
```

here also the same result...

```
SQL> select instr('stringrings','rin',4,1) from dual;

INSTR('STRINGRINGS','RIN',4,1)
------------------------------
                             7
```

but here, in positive direction search it ignores the partial pattern match and gives the position where the exact pattern matches.. Can anyone explain it to me? why this double standards?

Answer (score 2):

No double standarts:

```
select instr('stringrings','rin',-4,1) from dual;
```

INSTR start search from stringr**i**ngs (-4), searching backward until first **rin** = string**rin**gs (7)

```
select instr('stringrings','rin',-5,1) from dual;
```

INSTR start search from string**r**ings (-5), searching backward until first **rin** = string**rin**gs (7)

```
select instr('stringrings','rin',4,1) from dual;
```

INSTR start search from str**i**ngrings (4), searching foreward until first **rin** = string**rin**gs (7)

Comment: select instr('stringrings','rin',-4,1) from dual;

Comment: select instr('stringrings','rin',-4,1) from dual; INSTR starts search from stringrings (-4), so the content available for search on is 'stringri' as -4 = i; then how it finds 'rin', because it has found only 'ri'............please explain as here 'n' is out of search starting position

Comment: INSTR function does not "cut" string, so available content is "stringrings", not "stringri".